# Как исправить маленький баг?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если нажать кнопку 1, в элемент с классом `.tit_modal_email` должен вставится текст *"Landing Page Сартовий"*.

А если нажать вторую кнопку – *"Landing Page Середній"*.

Сейчас, если я нажму сначала кнопку 1, то текст при нажатии кнопки 2 не изменится, а если сначала нажму кнопку 2, то потом, при нажатии кнопки 1, текст вставится с кнопки 2.

Как исправить? где проблема?

```js
$("#order-landing-standart").click(function() {
  dataFormOrder("Landing Page Сартовий");
})

$("#order-landing-seredniy").click(function() {
  dataFormOrder("Landing Page Середній");
})

function dataFormOrder(data) {
  var lang = data;
  var content_mod = $(".tit_modal_email").text();

  if (!content_mod) {
    $(" ").append(lang);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tit_modal_email"></div>
<button id="order-landing-standart">1</button>
<button id="order-landing-seredniy">2</button>
```

Comment: Указанное поведение - не воспроизводится. текст не появляется никакой ни при каких условиях.

Answer (score 0):

```
function dataFormOrder(data){
    $(".tit_modal_email").text(data);    
}
```